# Call function to do anything at x minutes

Tags: c++, loops, time

i have spend a lot of time for it but i cant find the right way to do it.
I want a function thats called every x minutes to do over stuff, but without stopping my whole program. It's just a function in a large program.
I have tried a lot of functions like difftime or others, but everything stops my program and difftime does not work for me, like this one

```
void ProcStatistics(int thisarg)

time_t end;
time(&start);
while (1) {
time(&end);
double dif = difftime (end,start);
if (dif < 600) 
{
std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;

//do other stuff

std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
time(&end);
return detour_ProcStatistics->GetOriginalFunction()(thisarg);
}
```

I cant use sleep, maybe a loop or something else, with a break or continue.
The problem is that program time constantly updated, because it runs all the time.

Comment: Create a new thread that sleeps for x minutes, then calls your function. Problem solved.

Comment: What you want is a [thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/), but they're quite complex and lead to a lot of confusion among novice programmers.  The embedded way is easier to understand, but substantially less robust.  In your main loop you test to see if sufficient time has passed, and only call the function if it has.  This requires you to write your program in a way that the main loop cycles at a much faster rate than you want your function called.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, this is C+11 and above.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

//spawn a new thread as to not stop the whole program.
std::thread t([] {

    //call a function every n minutes
    while (1){
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(/*n minutes*/));
       function();
    }
});

//thread can now run in background, 
//and you don't have to worry about joining it.  
//i.e. a terminate call without an active exception
t.detach();
```

Comment: +1.  Certainly a great way to do this if you understand threads.  If not, it can be terribly problematic, and will result in some of the hardest to find bugs of (my, anyhow) career.  If you really want to learn about great coding practices, look into this, but if you're not willing to spend the effort learning, and you just copy and paste this code, it won't go well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, i have read about threads, but I dont really know how I can use it for this program. Maybe you can make a solution for me.
Small snippet from main.ccp:

```
int AffAddPoint(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
#ifdef TEST
std::cout << "(int)Points: " << (int)a2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "(LONGLONG)Points: " << (LONGLONG)a2 << std::endl;
#endif

detour_affinity->GetOriginalFunction()(a1, a2, a3);
}

// Function what i need ->
void ProcStatistics(int thisarg) 
{
{
 std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
        char const* godbless = " 410 5";
        ((void(*)(int, char const*))0x082249E4)(0, godbless);
        godbless = " 627 4";
        std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
        }
return detour_ProcStatistics->GetOriginalFunction()(thisarg);
}
// <- Function End

detour_ProcStatistics = simpleHook<tProcStatistics>((unsigned int)0x081E3934, ProcStatistics);

void ConnectDB()
{
mysql_init(&m_dbuserxx);
```

small snippet from main.h

```
typedef void (*tProcStatistics)(int);

MologieDetours::Detour<tProcStatistics>* detour_ProcStatistics= NULL;
```

Comment: Where did that code come from?  Holy cow there's a lot of terrible stuff in there.  Why are you using a hex literal to call a function?

Comment: Hex is to hook an other program, for this program there is no source public.

Comment: Well, two full code examples have been posted using C++11, can you use one of them? They're both very easy to understand.  The trick is that any data accessed from two different threads must be protected by mutices (not strictly true, but reasonable rule of thumb) like `std::mutex`

Comment: Yes of course it's C++11, the complete program run with all functions, but i dont know how can i say one function run every x minutes

Comment: I don't know how much clearer an example you could expect than the two already provided.  What part of those examples don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The code below would work better than anything using `sleep_for` if maintaining timing is critical.  If you're not sweating the microseconds, (picoseconds?) then Trevor's answer is a lot simpler.

Uses C++11 features.
Must be linked with -lpthread if using g++ (at least for mine)
Runs as written to give a simple and easy to understand demonstration

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

//This is where you set the rate to call repeated_function at
constexpr int ancilary_function_rate_minutes = 3;

//This is the function which will be called repeatedly
void repeated_function(void)
{
  //TODO: Put useful code here
  //TODO: Be aware of race conditions, use std::mutex variables to guard conflicts


  //This code should be discarded for actual use, but makes a reasonable demonstration

  static int i = 0;
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " " << i << std::endl;
  i++;
  return;
}

void ancilary_thread_main(void)
{
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp =
  std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 

  while(1)
  {
    //use the below line for minutes for intended application
    //tp += std::chrono::minutes(ancilary_function_rate_minutes);

    //use the below line for seconds to see it run in realtime
    tp += std::chrono::seconds(3);

    //Note the above two durations are additive, you could use both


    repeated_function(); //This is where the function gets called repeatedly


    //By using sleep_until instead of sleep_for, and by only calling now()
    //  once, we do not lose the time it takes to run repeated_function and
    //  allow our rate to drift
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);

    //Note that this will sleep AT LEAST until the given time, there is no
    //  guarantee that it will run then, but more likely will run the first
    //  time after that when a processor (core) becomes available.
  }
}

int main()
{
  //First launch the initial thread
  std::thread my_thread (ancilary_thread_main);


  //The rest of your code here


  //This code should be discarded for actual use, but makes a reasonable demonstration
  int i = 0;
  while(1) //Generally only acceptable in embedded applications
  {
    std::cout << "Main Thread " << i << std::endl;
    i++;
    //Because this look uses sleep_for, it will lose time over many iterations
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }

  my_thread.join(); //This is unreachable, but in application, main loop will eventually exit.
  return 0;
}
```